# what methods do you take when your linux kernel programs are wrong?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I did not find a good method when I write and test a linux kernel programs such as multiple kernel-level threads or other general kernel modules, what methods do you take? thanks in advance!

Comment: The general hint is to avoid kernel programming, and put as much as possible your code in user land. Needing kernel threads could be a design mistake.

Answer (score 1):

printk, printk and more printk.

use dmesg to view. crash the kernel sometimes deliberately to get the crashinfo, then you can decode the crashinfo

dumptrace(), dumpstack() will print the stacktrace on the dmesg.

As a last option, kgdb. but this requires a connection to another system and is a pain always to get it work.